# JSON, compressing it on client and server side

Tags: c#, javascript, json

Anybody knows of any utility that will compress JSON server side (C#), and re-constitute it into JSON on the client side and vice versa. My whole page view model is in json, and need to find a way to reduce size of it. I found cJSON, and RISON, but I don't see C# implementations.

Any ideas?

Clarification: On server side, I need to take a JSON string and register client side variable that is encoded/compressed to reduce the size. On the client side I need a utility that I can call from JavaScript to decode/uncompress it. Also need this in reverse order too.

Reference links:

cJson
http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=104

Rison
http://mjtemplate.org/examples/rison.html

Comment: Are you doing this for performance (because as everyone else has said the browser and server can be setup [and most are out of the box] to compress the traffic across the wire)?  Or for security (so people can't look at your data/api)?  Two different questions.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use HTTP compression and allow the browser/web server to handle the compression of the requests?

Comment: This.  gzip encoding is built into all the browsers as well as .NET.  Use it.

Comment: Also advisable to remove excess whitespace (newlines, tabs, etc, are only there to make it readable).  There'll be no need to do any extra work to decompress it at the client end, but you'll make a huge impact on the size of the response, even if you're gzipping.

Comment: @Mike: compression is done at the server level or not? I have no control over it. Second, even if I had, it is lot about appearances when view source is viewed. I need to compress it and than encode it.

Comment: Second … what?! Are you saying that giving the appearance of being compressed is as important as actually compressing it? Why?

Comment: @David: If you look at the RISON, even before gzip compresses it, it already shaves of 30-60% off. If I push it through cJson first, I can get probably another 10-20%. So it is not just appearance. And yes, also one should not be able to view the source and see what is in there, although nothing will prevent somebody from just decoding it, but that is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd second Llyod's answer and also add that you're not considering the client-side decompression overhead.

Deflate and gzip are worthwhile largely because browsers handle decompression in native code.  If you implement a custom JSON compression scheme, you'll have to decompress it using JavaScript, which will be significantly slower.  Unless you're doing that in a browser that supports Web Workers (i.e no versions of IE), that really isn't viable.  Either way, the JavaScript-based decompression would almost certainly add more latency than the compression would save.